# Covariance matrix after rotation

Tags: random, rotation, covariance, quaternions

I encountered this question when developing a Kalman filter for a moving target using a camera on a drone. The problem is:

Assume I have a position measurement p1 with covariance matrix R1. And I have another rotation which is in the form of a quaternion q. This quaternion has a covariance matrix R2. Then what is the covariance matrix after I rotate p1 by q?

I have googled for a very long time but could only find the solution when q is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use propagation of uncertainty by numeric formula 
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Using numeric derivatives (Jacobian)

2. Use MRPT implementation https://www.mrpt.org/
   as described in here http://ingmec.ual.es/~jlblanco/papers/jlblanco2010geometry3D_techrep.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I want.